# Undesirable output of my code while using JInternalFrame class

Tags: java, jinternalframe

I am learning JAVA swing and I have written code about JavaInternalFrame.
I do not know , where I am making mistakes. Everything looks good, but I am not getting the expected result. Below are my code and output:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

public class Jinternal extends JFrame {
JDesktopPane jd=new JDesktopPane();
JInternalFrame jInt=new  JInternalFrame("Chacha");

public Jinternal(){
    jInt.setMaximizable(true);
    jInt.setResizable(true);
    jInt.setIconifiable(true);
    //jInt.setSize(300,390);
    jInt.setClosable(true);
    jInt.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    jInt.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    jInt.setVisible(true);
    jd.add(jInt);
    add(jd);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Jinternal JI = new Jinternal();
    JI.setVisible(true);
    JI.setSize(600,450);
    JI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

}

[output of my code][1]}
```

In my output frame i am not able to see the Internal frame.

[image: Picture of my output]

Comment: It would help if you tell us what you expect as output.

Comment: in my output frame i am not able to see the Internal frame.

Comment: I tried to attach a image file but, stack overflow did not allow that beacuse i do not have enough points.

Comment: Thank you !
 i got the answer, by mistake i commented the line with setSize code for  internal frame. So i think , we have to set size for internal frame.

Comment: I edited your question to show the picture correctly.